# Need to optimize network utilization on IOS platform. Is there any reference?

Tags: ios, optimization, networking

Is there any Apple reference or guidelines to understand when to transmit data from application? Scenarios include : Just trigger the HTTP connection when the radio has just been active. 
        Also the optimal data size for a single burst would be helpful to optimize my app. I'd appreciate any references on this end.

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides a class called "Reachability" which would probably help you. It can trigger callbacks when the network status changes, i.e. connection becomes available.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html